# How to convert a string to camelCase in Go?

Tags: go

What is the simplest way to convert a string with spaces to a single camelCased string?

For example: "This is a string with spaces" -> "thisIsAStringWithSpaces"

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I like to use this library
https://github.com/iancoleman/strcase

```
strcase.ToLowerCamel("This is a string with spaces")
```

Answer (score 2):

Can avoid regex if only dealing with spaces. See [`strings`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings) package for useful helpers that can be used to expand this functionality:

```
str := "This is a string with spaces"
words := strings.Split(str, " ")
key := strings.ToLower(words[0])
for _, word := range words[1:] {
    key += strings.Title(word)
}
log.Println(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the two existing answers have some issues, so I wrote a custom function instead.

I had been using a solution that leveraged strings.Title() like [@sam-berry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70083838/1021430), but that has been deprecated as of go1.18 (Mar 15, 2022). The library in [@david-yappeter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70083960/1021430) doesn't appear to use that function, but it seems like it might behave badly if the string contains any unicode.

Since the strings.Title() deprecation statement says to use the cases package, I wrote this function that removes any problematic characters like unicode or punctuation, treats underscores like spaces, and uses cases.Title().String() to do the casing.

```
func camelCase(s string) string {

    // Remove all characters that are not alphanumeric or spaces or underscores
    s = regexp.MustCompile("[^a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+").ReplaceAllString(s, "")

    // Replace all underscores with spaces
    s = strings.ReplaceAll(s, "_", " ")

    // Title case s
    s = cases.Title(language.AmericanEnglish, cases.NoLower).String(s)

    // Remove all spaces
    s = strings.ReplaceAll(s, " ", "")

    // Lowercase the first letter
    if len(s) > 0 {
        s = strings.ToLower(s[:1]) + s[1:]
    }

    return s
}
```